# How can I remove a package and its dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

How can I go back to the state before the package was installed?

Install:

```
# apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends build-essential
...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2 libatomic1
  libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libgcc-5-dev libgdbm3
  libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0 libperl5.22
  libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make patch
  perl perl-modules-5.22 xz-utils
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-5-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib
  g++-5-multilib gcc-5-doc libstdc++6-5-dbg gcc-multilib manpages-dev autoconf
  automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc gcc-5-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan2-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg
  libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc
  libstdc++-5-doc make-doc ed diffutils-doc perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
  | libterm-readline-perl-perl
Recommended packages:
  fakeroot libalgorithm-merge-perl manpages manpages-dev
  libfile-fcntllock-perl rename
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils build-essential cpp cpp-5 dpkg-dev g++ g++-5 gcc gcc-5 libasan2
  libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libgcc-5-dev
  libgdbm3 libgomp1 libisl15 libitm1 liblsan0 libmpc3 libmpfr4 libmpx0
  libperl5.22 libquadmath0 libstdc++-5-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev
  make patch perl perl-modules-5.22 xz-utils
```

Removal:

```
# apt-get -y --purge --auto-remove remove build-essential
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  build-essential*

# apt-get -y --purge autoremove
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  g++* g++-5* libstdc++-5-dev*
```

Why is the other stuff kept?

Comment: Because `build-essential` is sort of those apt packages which are called `metapackage` or virtual package. They are created to pull other packages as a _feature set_ and removing them won't cause removal of pulled packages

Comment: @Anwar, there isn't a special notion for that on the dpkg or apt level. The metapackages  are just like the others.

Comment: No. metapackages are different and see my comment on _your_ answer

Answer (score 2):

In short:

`sudo bash -c 'echo "Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant false;" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-suggested'`

This behavior is controlled by the option `Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant`.

> Option: Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant
>
> Default: true
>
> Description: If this option is true, then aptitude will
> not consider packages to be unused (and thus will not automatically
> remove them) as long as any installed package suggests them. For more
> information, see the section called “Managing automatically installed
> packages”.

Source:

[Aptitude doesn't remove automatically installed packages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106670/146335)

Comment: You were not using aptitude, you were using `apt` which is different. And `apt` always suggest to remove automatically installed packages that are no longer required

Comment: @Anwar, the config value is in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` and called `Apt::`, and it works, so it's definitely for apt-get. I do the apt-cacher proxy configs for apt-get in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` too...